# How to rowspan records in jqgrid

Tags: jquery, jqgrid, html-table

How can I use rowspan in jqgrid..?
Anyone can help me..?

Comment: I suppose that you know that it is not possible directly. So to implement it it some special situation you should describe more clear your case. How you imagine to use rows selection and hovering in case of `rowspan` usage? Which row should be selected/hovered? Or you need for rows headers only and not for the rows from the grid body?